# Is it false that the complement of an open set is closed?

Tags: general-topology, definition

> Let $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a continuous function.
>
> Let $Z(f)$ be the zero of $f$.
>
> Prove that $Z(f)$ is closed.

This is one of problems in my mid-term exam. I have used $\epsilon-\delta$ argument and showed that the complement of $Z(f)$ is open. Hence, $Z(f)$ is closed.

The problem is my professor didn't marked my answer sheet, but a teaching assistant marked it and he marked it wrong. He said, "there is a counter example that a complement of an open set is not closed".

I have no words. As far as i know, **that is the definition of closed sets**. Am i wrong?

Comment: Yes, a set is closed iff its complement is open.

Comment: I edited your question title and tags to something that I think better reflects the real heart of your question. Feel free to revert the edit if you disagree.

Comment: I believe that the teaching assistant is wrong.  You should (politely and calmly!) speak to your professor about this.

Comment: There are other possible definitions of a closed set.  For example, I think Rudin's analysis textbook defines a closed set as one which contains all its limit points.  But in all cases, the fact that the complement of an open set is closed should be either a definition or a theorem (or else someone is using *very* unusual terminology).

Comment: If $C$ is a  closed set then, the inverse  image $f^{-1}(C)$, with $f$ continuous is an set closed. in this case $C=\{(0,0)\}$ that is a closed set.

Comment: @AsdrubalBeltran: That's true but it doesn't really address the question.

Comment: If I were you, I'd ask the teaching assistant to present a counterexample to you. ;)

Comment: A confusion in some students arise when they learn that "$A$ is open" and "$A$ is closed" are not contradictory, and hence the implication  "$A$ is open $\iff$ $A$ is not closed" is false. One should not confuse that with "$A$ is open  $\iff$ $A_c$ is closed", which is true.

Comment: Ask him what the counterexample is- haha!  I'd like to see it! No need to talk to the professor yet.  I would go to the TA as I think the TA is just confused.

Comment: ... or, put, in other (not very good) way: "the complement of an open set is a closed set" is true. "the complement of the set of all open sets is the set of all closed sets" is false.

Answer (score 1):

*This community wiki solution is intended to clear the question from the unanswered queue.*

---

The complement of an open set is closed. This is one definition of being closed.

Alternatively, notice that $\mathbb C$ is Hausdorff and so singletons are closed, in particular $\{0\}$ is closed. One definition of a function being continuous is that inverse images of closed sets are closed, thus $Z(f) = f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is closed.